# Quick Sort infinite loop Numerical Recipies

Tags: c++, c, sorting, infinite-loop

I am trying to export some code from MATLAB to MEX files (a.la C). For the code segment i am trying to export i need to implement an algorithm that can sort a 2D array. Opening up a copy of numerical recipes i find the index based sort. I have implemented this function with zero indexing, in a simple fashion which I will simplify later. The problem currently stands that when i run my function it will enter an infinite loop when passed certain sets of random numbers. For example the set:

```
0.8147,
0.9058,
0.127,
0.9134,
0.6324,
0.0975,
0.2785,
0.5469,
0.9575,
0.9649,
0.1576,
0.9706,
0.9572,
0.4854,
0.8003,
0.1419,
0.4218,
0.9157,
0.7922,
0.9595
```

None of these numbers repeat. Below is my version of the Numerical Recipies in C code. Any suggestions as to what is wrong? I have spent 3 hours on this. The algorithm provides the proper indexes on well behaved sets of random numbers.

```
#define SWAP(a,b) itemp=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=itemp;
#define M 7
#define NSTACK 50

long* IndexSort(unsigned long int vectorLength, double* column)
{

unsigned long i, indxt, ir = vectorLength, itemp,j, k, l = 1;
int jstack = 0, *istack;
long *indx;
double a;

istack = (int*)malloc(NSTACK*sizeof(int));
//initalize output
indx = (long*)malloc(vectorLength*sizeof(long));

for (j = 0; j < vectorLength; j++)
{
    indx[j] = j;

}

// 
while (true)
{
    if (ir - l < M)
    {   
        for (j = l+1; j <= ir;j++)
        {
            indxt = indx[j-1];
            a = column[indxt];
            for (i = j-1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                if (column[indx[i - 1]] <= a)
                {
                    break;
                }
                indx[i + 1 - 1] = indx[i - 1];
            }
            indx[i + 1 - 1] = indxt;
        }
        if (jstack == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        ir = istack[jstack--];
        l = istack[jstack--];
    }
    else
    {   

        k = (l + ir) >> 1;

        SWAP(indx[k - 1], indx[l + 1 - 1])

        if (column[indx[l + 1 - 1]] > column[indx[ir - 1]]){
            SWAP(indx[l + 1 - 1], indx[ir - 1])
        }

        if (column[indx[l - 1]] > column[indx[ir - 1]]){
            SWAP(indx[l - 1], indx[ir - 1])
        }

        if (column[indx[l + 1 - 1]] > column[indx[l - 1]]){
            SWAP(indx[l + 1 - 1], indx[l - 1])
        }

        i = l + 1;
        j = ir;
        indxt = indx[l - 1];
        a = column[indxt];
        while (true)
        {
            do i++; while (column[indx[i - 1]] < a);
            do j--; while (column[indx[j - 1]] > a);
            if (j < i) break;
            SWAP(indx[i - 1], indx[j - 1])
        }
        indx[l - 1] = indx[j - 1];
        indx[j - 1] = indxt;
        jstack += 2;
        if (jstack > NSTACK) error("NSTACK too small for IndexSort");

        if (ir - i + 1 > j - 1){
            istack[jstack] = ir;
            istack[jstack - 1] = l;
            ir = j - 1;
        }

        else{
            istack[jstack] = j - 1;
            istack[jstack - 1] = l;
            l = i;
        }


    }
}
free(istack);
return indx;
}
```

**Edit 1:** 
I added my #defines to the top.
In response to the first wave of comments:

- This function call produces an array of sorted indices. I will take these values and use them to sort the 2D array. I apologize I should have been more clear about that.
- As for using the debugger that is currently not possible. The function is being called from a MEX wrapper. I will write up a main function to so I can investigate this.

**Edit 2:**

- Moved the free command as suggested still no change.
- Update problem statement. I was reading problems on the forums and most people have a crash. My problem is actually an infinite-loop and i don't know where it is initiating.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Will

Comment: Where's the 2D part of this array ? If this indeed crashes as you describe, I would think a *debugger* would make short work of telling you the general location of where the wheels fell off.

Comment: `it will crash when passed certain sets of random numbers`  Probably has nothing to do with the numbers.  You're probably overstepping the bounds of your arrays.  Also this -- `Opening up a copy of numerical recipes`  Why not just use `std::sort`? `std::sort(column, column + vectorLength);`

Comment: What are `NSTACK` and `M`?

Comment: You `free(istack)` in an unlikely place.

Comment: Ugh! That's been ported from some old Fortran code: `l` is the left index and the corresponding right index is `ir` - i can't be just `r` because then you'd have to declare it instead of relying on implicit type by inferrence from the first letter. Also: `indx[l + 1 - 1]`.

Comment: No-one will easily follow your code, and in six months or less, neither will you, if you do now! Following @PaulMcKenzie there are suspicious loop start and end conditions throughout. And with statements like `do i++; while (column[indx[i - 1]] < a);` it is almost impossible to read the intent of the code.

Comment: Is your goal to simply sort the indices based on the values?  If so, this is a simple matter using `C++` and `std::sort`.  You don't need all of this code to do the job.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So being new to the `C++` game i have not grasped the STL completely yet. I assume I can't pass `std::sort` a c style array. Do the `std::arrays` work the same after their declaration?

Comment: @crazywill32 You can pass an array to `std::sort`.  See my answer.

Comment: I have a major suggestion: never use quicksort. There's no legitimate reason for it. Use a heapsort like any sensible programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to sort indices from a given array, the following code using C++ 11, `std::sort` and lambdas should do the job:

**C++11 example**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

long* IndexSort(unsigned long int vectorLength, double* column)
{
    long *index = new long[vectorLength](); // I really don't recommend this line
    long n = 0;
    std::generate( index, index + vectorLength, [&] { return n++; });
    std::sort(index, index + vectorLength, [&](long v1, long v2) 
             { return column[v1] < column[v2]; });
    return index;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
  std::array<double,20> testData = 
                        {0.8147,0.9058,0.127,0.9134,0.6324,0.0975,0.2785,
                        0.5469,0.9575,0.9649,0.1576,0.9706,0.9572,0.4854,
                        0.8003,0.1419,0.4218,0.9157,0.7922,0.9595};
  long *indices = IndexSort(testData.size(), &testData[0]);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < testData.size(); ++i )
    cout << testData[indices[i]] << "  has an index of " << indices[i] << "\n";
  delete [] indices;
}
```

Live Example:  http://ideone.com/EsOFKt

Note that all we did was to build an index array sorted, and compared the original double vector using the two indices passed to the lambda.

Note that allocating memory in the beginning for the indices isn't necessary, as a `std::vector<long>` would be the usual way to do this.  However I tried to mimic your original code requirements of returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.

---

**C++ 0x, 98 example**

If you are using a pre-C++ 11 compiler, you can change the code to this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct IndexSorter
{
   double *m_array;
   IndexSorter(double *oArray) : m_array(oArray) {}
   bool operator()(long v1, long v2) const { return m_array[v1] < m_array[v2]; }
};

long* IndexSort(unsigned long int vectorLength, double* column)
{
    long *index = new long[vectorLength](); // I really don't recommend this line
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < vectorLength; ++i) 
        index[i] = i;

    std::sort(index, index + vectorLength, IndexSorter(column));
    return index;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
  double testData[] =   {0.8147,0.9058,0.127,0.9134,0.6324,0.0975,0.2785,
                        0.5469,0.9575,0.9649,0.1576,0.9706,0.9572,0.4854,
                        0.8003,0.1419,0.4218,0.9157,0.7922,0.9595};
  unsigned long testSize = sizeof(testData) / sizeof(testData[0]);
  long *indices = IndexSort(testSize, &testData[0]);
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < testSize; ++i )
    cout << testData[indices[i]] << "  has an index of " << indices[i] << "\n";
  delete [] indices;
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/nhMwSs

---

**C example**

Since this question was also tagged as `C`, here is a `C` implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static double *myArray;

int compareIndices(const void* v1, const void *v2)
{
    long val1 = *(long *)v1;
    long val2 = *(long *)v2;
    if (myArray[val1] < myArray[val2])
        return -1;
    else
    if ( myArray[val1] > myArray[val2])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

long* IndexSort(unsigned long int vectorLength, double* column)
{
    myArray = column;
    long *index = malloc(vectorLength * sizeof(long));
    if ( index )
    {
        unsigned long i;
        for (i = 0; i < vectorLength; ++i)
            index[i] = i;
        qsort(index, vectorLength, sizeof(long), compareIndices);
        return index;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double testData[] = { 0.8147, 0.9058, 0.127, 0.9134, 0.6324, 0.0975, 0.2785,
        0.5469, 0.9575, 0.9649, 0.1576, 0.9706, 0.9572, 0.4854,
        0.8003, 0.1419, 0.4218, 0.9157, 0.7922, 0.9595 };
    unsigned long numItems = sizeof(testData) / sizeof(testData[0]);
    long *indices = IndexSort(numItems, testData);
    if ( indices )
    {
        unsigned long i;
        for (i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
            printf("%lf has an index of %ld\n", testData[indices[i]], indices[i]);
        free(indices);
    }
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/8SZH1m

Comment: Thanks for that. I started as a C person and while i begin to grasp some of the concepts in C++ I am still learning. This was really helpful. Looks like i need to spend more time on some of the other pieces of it.

Comment: Well basically, you could have done this in C.  Just create your indices the same way originally, and use `qsort` on the indices.  However, I don't recommend it for C++ work -- just stick with `std::sort`.